# Check-table shown in selection screen for a parameter

Tags: parameters, abap, sap-selection-screens

I want to get a check table for input suggestions on a parameter while running this selection screen. Check table for the domain is set correctly and it is shown right in the table maintenance, but in the program I get no suggestion. This is the declaration of that parameter in the selection-screen.

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 200.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK B2 WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-t02.  
Parameters p_empsu  TYPE Z0B_SU.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK B2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 200.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add detailed information about the data types, preferably with screenshots

Comment: I don't understand what happens with posting photos.

Comment: Isn't the table empty?

Comment: No, it has values. And I can see them in the maintenance views when I add another entry.

Comment: Instead of parameters: ... Type ....please try parameters: ... Like table_or_struct-field.

Comment: I tryed the 'like' but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you've run into one of the many inconsistencies in ABAP that you'll simply have to accept. Read the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abapparameters_type.htm) carefully - although I get the impression that it's not as clear in the English version. Basically, you need to use a structure or table field reference if you want to get the automatic value help additions, so try

```
PARAMETERS p_empsu TYPE z0b_Service_unit-service_unit.
```

Another - often preferable - option is to define a search help and assign it explicitly using `MATCHCODE OBJECT`.